# How to make an image with text animation at hover mouse signal - HTML + CSS + JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

I am building a website as a presentation of product for my client and I have the need to clone the following feature:

[image: Hover Effect]

Anyone know how to achieve this?

You can preview the `CatWalk Demo` in the following link: https://www.templatemonster.com/demo/61202.html

Comment: looks like a show/hide with some minor animation, can be done with css, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what are you looking for?

```css
/*
 * Housekeeping
 */
body {
    font: normal 16px/1.5 Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1, p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 0 .5em;
}

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 480px;
}

/*
 * Caption component
 */
.caption {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;

    /* Only the -webkit- prefix is required these days */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
            transform: translateZ(0);
}

.caption::before {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    transition: background .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover::before {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.caption__media {
    display: block;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.caption__overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px;
    color: white;

    -webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
            transform: translateY(100%);

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}

.caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY( -webkit-calc(-100% - 10px) );
            transform: translateY( calc(-100% - 10px) );

    transition: -webkit-transform .35s ease-out;
    transition:         transform .35s ease-out;
}

.caption:hover .caption__overlay__title {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

    <article class="caption">
        <img class="caption__media" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6088/6128773012_bd09c0bb4e_z_d.jpg" />
        <div class="caption__overlay">
            <h1 class="caption__overlay__title">Alaska</h1>
            <p class="caption__overlay__content">
                Alaska is a U.S. state situated in the northwest extremity of the North American continent. Bordering the state is Canada to the east, the Arctic Ocean to the north, and the Pacific Ocean to the west and south, with Russia (specifically, Siberia) further west across the Bering Strait.
            </p>
        </div>
    </article>

</div>
```

Took me literally 4 seconds searching google and 4 to paste and answer it 
From that [dude](https://jsfiddle.net/i_like_robots/7GvV2/)